# Android Studio gradle build successfully despite api level error

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, build.gradle

I am working on an android project that Api level is 10,  its is declared in build.gradle and AndroidManifest.xml files

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 15
}

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

When I use ActionBar class Android Studio Editor underlined this line and gave warning as I expected "Call requires API level 11(current min is 10):android.app.ActionBar..."

but when I compile project , it is compiled successfully. It can be cause errors , how can it be worked on API lvl 10 devices.I want an error about this, but it compiled.How can I get a build error about this. ty.

Comment: what is the `compileSdkVersion` in your `build.gradle` ?

Comment: It was 18 , I set it 10 ,and I took lots of error about Holo although I didnt chose this theme . _(AndroidStudioProjects\TeAppProject\TeApp\build\exploded-bundles\ComAndroidSupportAppcompatV71800.aar\res\values-v14\values.xml , Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionButton'etc..)_ But yes I think its about compileSdkVersion.If I skip all this error,I can get error I mentioned about the post. ty @Varun

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is the Android lint tool displaying errors, but Android Studio still allowing compilation.

This is because the lint errors you see do not prevent compilation. It seems that Android Studio (at least in v1.3.2) the build process ignores lint errors during compilation by default, whereas in Eclipse w/ ADT plugin you would not be able to compile.

Looking at [Improving with Lint](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/improving-w-lint.html#studio), you can modify your build.gradle file with lint options in order to have the build fail:

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        // if true, stop the gradle build if errors are found
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change below...

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 15
}

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

After setting gradle or menifest. clean and rebuild your project. hope it will work.... if still not working restart tool and try to compile project again....

Comment: This is not the solution the OP wants. The OP still wants the error to be shown. The OP also wants the application to **fail compilation**, but Android Studio is still compiling the application (Eclipse with ADT did not have this behavior).